# How can the hostname go missing on Linux?

Tags: linux, centos, hostname

How can a Linux server lose its hostname?  This might be a loaded question, but there might be several answers.  I just need to diagnose the problem I'm having, but I don't know where to start.

Perhaps you can help me figure out how Linux determines the output for this command?  I'll accept that as an answer as well.

```
[root@xyz ~]# hostname -f
hostname: Unknown host
```

This issue was what allowed me to determine the hostname was missing:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484275/what-causes-the-error-java-net-unknownhostexception

## **EDIT:**

Per this comment, I've pasted the /etc/hosts file below.  It doesn't look like the hostname is found in there.  This is CentOS.  D34DM347, what OS are you looking at the man pages in?

> The man page for hostname indicates the -f option returns the FQDN,
>   usually defined in /etc/hosts linux.die.net/man/1/hostname – D34DM347

/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

Comment: The man page for `hostname` indicates the -f option returns the FQDN, usually defined in `/etc/hosts` http://linux.die.net/man/1/hostname

Comment: D34DM347, please see edit.  Do you have a server where the hostname is found in your /etc/hosts?  Also, what distribution are you looking at?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter which distort. Typically there would be another entry in `/etc/hosts` which lists your hostname and IP address. Have you tried setting the hostname with `hostname servername`?

Comment: *Perhaps you can help me figure out how Linux determines the output for this command?* - see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164089/where-does-hostname-store-the-hostname-that-ive-set Distro specific, depends on systemd or not systemd. Might be `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/hostname` or `/etc/sysconfig/network` or `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` or none of the above.

Comment: You forgot to mention which distribution version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm running CentOS7 and my hostname is written under all the ipv4 / ipv6 entries. Try adding a line at the bottom of /etc/hosts with

```
[your IP address] [your hostname]
```

Also you can update (although I didn't have to for my servers)

/etc/sysconfig/network

```
 NETWORKING="yes"
 GATEWAY="10.1.1.1"
 HOSTNAME="www.example.com"
```

You'll have to restart networking at least, generally I do a full reboot though.

```
systemctl restart network
```

or

```
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: What am I adding a line to?  /etc/hosts?

Comment: Yes, /etc/hosts

Comment: This works, but I'm just wondering if it's the best answer.  Because doesn't the kernal also store it?

Comment: It should be, try updating /etc/sysconfig/network too based on my edit.

Comment: Is /etc/sysconfig/network the kernal value?

Comment: /etc/hosts survives a restart so it MAY be the kernel value. I don't want to lead you down the wrong path there so you should investigate more if you need to know down to that level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32817/discussion-between-red-shift-and-macgyver).